# get Field name from the query builder result

Tags: laravel

I need to get field names from the query builder result.
For a single table
I could use

```
DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('table_name');
```

but what i need is from the query builder result.

```
   DB::table('users as a')
->leftJoin('userwork AS uk','uk.WORK_ID', '=','a.WORK_ID')
->selectRaw("a. name ,uk.work_name as work ,concat('+',uk.work_phone) as phone")
->get();
```

I want to extract the attribute name to get the result like below

```
['name','work','phone'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using array_keys method after converting the first result of the query builder to array.

```
$db_fields=array_keys((array)$items->first());
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you need like this?

```
DB::table('users as a')
->leftJoin('userwork AS uk','uk.WORK_ID', '=','a.WORK_ID')
->select("a. name ,uk.work_name as work ,concat('+',uk.work_phone) as phone")
->get();
```

just using **select**. You could write on your controller.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).